# Multinomial Logit Choice Model in R with mnlogit()

Tags: r, mlogit

I have question regarding the `mnlogit` package in R which I'll ask on StackOverflow as it's related to a specific language and library, however I won't be offended if someone decides to move it to Cross Validated (it was a hard choice of which StackExchange site was most appropriate).

I'm just trying to make sure I understand how this works, since the documentation isn't too detailed, I see some confusing/conflicting blog entries on this package, and because it's been a couple of years since I've dealt with choice models.

The example usage of `mnlogit` is basically as follows:

```
> require(mnlogit)
> data(Fish)
> head(Fish)
           mode   income     alt   price  catch chid
1.beach   FALSE 7083.332   beach 157.930 0.0678    1
1.boat    FALSE 7083.332    boat 157.930 0.2601    1
1.charter  TRUE 7083.332 charter 182.930 0.5391    1
1.pier    FALSE 7083.332    pier 157.930 0.0503    1
2.beach   FALSE 1250.000   beach  15.114 0.1049    2
2.boat    FALSE 1250.000    boat  10.534 0.1574    2
> fm <- formula(mode ~ price | income | catch)
> result <- mnlogit(fm, Fish, "alt", ncores = 2)
```

What I find confusing is `mode` and `alt`. I would've thought that the dependent variable would be the multinomial choice, which appears to be `alt` (beach, boat, charter, or pier).

Instead it's this logical variable, `mode`. What's `mode`?

To try to clarify my understand I read an [R-Bloggers article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/comparing-mnlogit-and-mlogit-for-discrete-choice-models/) on the topic. It actually made things more confusing by repeating the `Fish` example, but with a preamble describing the dataset in this way:

> A data frame containing :
>
> ```
> mode - The choice set: beach, pier, boat, and charter
> price - price for a mode for an individual
> catch - fish catch rate for a mode for an individual
> income - monthly income of the individual decision-maker
> chid - decision maker ID
> ```

It describes `mode` as if it were `alt` then does not mention `alt`. Can someone explain this to me?

If `mode` really did take on the discrete choice values as described in the R-Bloggers article, then the model `formula(mode ~ price | income | catch)` would make sense to me... but `mode` is a logical variable, so I am thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, okay. I think I see now -- `mode` indicates which of the four possible choices was chosen, given the characteristics of each choice set. That makes sense.